# Where to add index buffer size in Elasticsearch 6x

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-6

I want to increase the buffer size for elasticsearch in template settings, but where should I add this setting. Where should I write `indices.memory.index_buffer_size:`? As I understand it should be defined for the index, actually I have one index.

```
const indexTemplateSettings = {
    number_of_shards: 2,
    number_of_replicas : 0,
    refresh_interval: '3600s',
    'indices.memory.index_buffer_size': '30%',
    // 'store.throttle.max_bytes_per_sec' : '100mb',
    max_result_window: 1000000000,
    'index.routing.allocation.enable': 'all',
}

export const init = async types => {
    try {
        let client = createClient()

        const templateSettings = {
            index_patterns : ['*'],
            settings: indexTemplateSettings,
            mappings : types.reduce((p, type) => ({
                ...p,
                [type] : {
                    numeric_detection: true,
                    _source : {enabled : true},
                    dynamic_templates: [
                        {
                            all: {
                                match: '*',
                                mapping: {
                                    copy_to: searchField,
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                    properties: {
                        _searchField: {
                            type: 'text',
                        },
                    },
                },
            }), {}),
        }

        await client.indices.putTemplate({
            name: 'default',
            body: templateSettings,
        },(error, response) => {
            logger.silly('Pushing of index template completed', response)
        })
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error(e)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should go to the *elasticsearch.yml* configuration file. Quoting from the [relevant docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/indexing-buffer.html):

> The following settings are static and must be configured on every data node in the cluster

Default is 10% of the heap. That is a node wide setting and not on a per index base.

On a side note: This should be [512MB per shard as the maximum as described in the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/tune-for-indexing-speed.html#_indexing_buffer_size).